# Layout Changes after Activity is Completed

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-activity

I am creating an android app and I want to make it so that if I click a button, it will switch to a different layout in a different activity. I will have to add a lot more code in to the activity, so just changing layouts within the first view is not an option. I want my `Main` activity to be linked with my `main.xml` and `searchResults` activity to be with `search_results.xml` Here is my source code in my Main activity:

```
public void OnResult(View v)
{
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(ParseStarterProjectActivity.this, searchResults.class);
    ParseStarterProjectActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
}
```

`OnResult` is called by the onClick event within my xml file. My `searchResults` activity looks like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.school_results);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "In searchResults Activity!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    finish();
```

When I was debugging I found out that it is calling `searchResults`, but it is not displaying the layout. It is going away from my main layout, but it isn't displaying my search_results layout. It is displaying the toast properly too. 
The only error I got in the logcat was:

```
Parent View is not a TextView
```

Any help would be appreciated as this problem is putting my project at a standstill.

**Edit:** Here is my searchResults.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
         android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/EditText01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button01"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />
    </TableRow>

<TableRow
         android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/EditText01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: post your search_results.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `finish()` on your `SearchResults` Activity in `onCreate()`, thus the Activity is closed almost as soon as it is opened.

If you remove `finish()` from `onCreate()`, I believe you will find that you see your new layout.

Comment: Wow. It was as simple as that. I thought I tried that before, but I guess I didn't do it properly then. Thanks a lot!